# Jersey REST client following URI returned in previous response

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using the Jersey Client API (2.0) to interact with a web service.  One of the calls results in a json object that has a 'next' value.  This value points at the resource that we should query to obtain the next set of items in a long list.

```
{
  "results":[.....]
  "next":"/path/to/next/resource?someparam=someval&etc"
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to target this new URL...  Yes, I can parse the URL to get the query portion of it, then break apart each parameter and then reverse the process to configure the WebTarget, but this seems like a lot of additional work given that I've already got the URL that I need to hit.

I've tried just passing the above into the path() method, but that doesn't work b/c JerseyWebTarget encodes the path.

If it matters, I do want to still inherit the filters/etc... from the source WebTarget.

So I'm looking for something like this:

```
WebTarget source = ....;
ListResult listResult = source.request().get();
display(listResult);
while (listResult.hasNext()){
  listResult = source.path(listResult.getNextUrl()).request().get();
  display(listResult);  
}
```

but where the path() call allows passing of the full relative URL...

EDIT - add example:

For reference, here is what I've had to do to make this work (if the URL contains more than just a relative path and a query parameter string, it will break):

```
    String nextUrl = previous.getNextUrl();
    int qPos = nextUrl.indexOf('?');
    int pathLen = qPos >= 0 ? qPos : nextUrl.length();

    WebTarget nextTarget = rootWebTarget.path(nextUrl.substring(0, pathLen));
    if (qPos > 0){
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = UriComponent.decodeQuery(nextUrl.substring(qPos+1), true);

        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : params.entrySet()){
            nextTarget = nextTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toArray());
        }

    }
```

Comment: For these types of applications I typically keep a WebTarget instance around that points to the root resource and then build the actual endpoint calls using `root.path("my/app/path").request()`. If you did that, you could simplly reuse the base `root` target for your next result get.

Comment: @Baldy yes - this is what I'm doing. The question is how to hit the 'next' URL when it includes query parameters.  As far as I can tell, the value I pass to path() cannot have query parameters b/c Jersey will encode the ? etc...

Comment: Got it. I missed that part of the question. You should be able to do this: `root.getUriBuilder().path("path with parameters").build()` and use that to get the new `WebTarget` from your client: `client.target(myUri)'. I haven't tried it but that should work since your `root` contains the base URI already.

Comment: @Baldy I started down that path, then realized that the filters/etc... configured on my base target wouldn't carry over...  I'll noodle on it a bit more. thanks.